# PHP Notice: Undefined index id Not recording in the database

Tags: php, mysql

Good afternoon, an error in the admin

When I enter the page, it shows errors.

Not recording in the database

Can you fix that code below?

Thank you very much for the help.

PHP Notice:  Undefined index: id in /genel-ayarlar.php on line 41

```html
<?
include ("../db.php");
$id=(int)$_GET['id'];
$calistir = mysql_query("select * from genelayarlar order by id DESC LIMIT 1") or die("An error occurred! ".mysql_error());
$sor = mysql_fetch_assoc($calistir);
?>
```

PHP Notice:  Undefined index: id in /genel-ayarlar.php on line 199

```html
<?
include ("../db.php");
$id=(int)$_GET['id'];
$calistir = mysql_query("select * from logo order by id DESC LIMIT 1") or die("An error occurred! ".mysql_error());
$gor = mysql_fetch_assoc($calistir);
?>
```

Comment: `mysql_query()` . . . I thought that was lost in the annals of history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int)$_GET['id'] : null;
```

Comment: Oops, it worked OK RESOLVED Thanks friend @Mateusz Pęczkowski

Comment: I did not find here in this post, the friend Mateusz Pęczkowski was that helped me a lot
And problem was RESOLVED